# Did the Chinese government give any specifics as to why it believes the U.S. doesn't treat China as an equal?

Tags: united-states, china

> The Chinese embassy in Washington said Wang told Sullivan that Taiwan
> independence “poses the biggest risk to cross-Strait peace and
> stability and the biggest challenge to China-US relations”. It said
> Wang called for the two countries to treat each other as equals,
> “instead of in a condescending way”.

https://www.ft.com/content/f4fe30ce-3cbf-47f0-a1ad-7574b59f6f04

Did the Chinese government give any specifics as to why it believes the U.S. doesn't treat China as an equal? I often see Chinese officials make that claim, but I never saw them give any example as to why they think it's the case. Was there any example given during an official response? I am thinking since the government publish a lot of white papers on various things, it might have been done already.

Comment: "you don't treat me as an equal" often equals "you don't give me what I want".

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Uh uh , "You don't treat me as an equal" often equals "You take more from me than you give me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the United States has implemented the hegemonic style of the only superpower at all times. The primacy of American interests is their creed, so diplomatic equality does not exist. This is reflected in many aspects. [***The Chinese Ministry of Foreign Affairs released a report systematically elaborating on this series of inequalities.***](https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjbxw/202302/t20230220_11027664.html) Due to limited space, I will only cite two aspects.

*Note: I quoted two Chinese sections of Wikipedia because the content provided by the English section is not comprehensive and is less than 1/2 of the English section. Methods for identifying whether the Chinese and English content are comprehensive are attached at the end.*

1. **Unilateral sanctions**

The United States has [***imposed sanctions on China for thirty years***](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E5%9C%8B%E5%B0%8D%E4%B8%AD%E8%8F%AF%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9C%8B%E7%9A%84%E5%88%B6%E8%A3%81), and the reasons for the sanctions are very diverse: 1. Being close to countries hostile to the United States. 2. American companies are at a disadvantage when competing with Chinese companies. 3. Human rights accusations against Xinjiang, Tibet and other regions without actual evidence. 4. Enterprises provide technical support to the People's Liberation Army. 5. Failure to cooperate with US sanctions.

The most typical sanctions are sanctions against Huawei, DJI, semiconductor manufacturers and restrictions on the export of memory chips to China.

Above the Notes(注释 in Chinese) on the Wikipedia page, you can see hundreds of Chinese companies and educational institutions sanctioned by the United States.

2. **Long-standing regional threats in the South China Sea**

The United States, together with Japan, South Korea, the Philippines and other countries, has formed an encirclement network of [***110 military bases in the first island chain***](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E5%B3%B6%E9%8F%88) (the English version of Wikipedia does not mention 110 military bases), and has deployed the most advanced military equipment. The United States relies on its military deployment in the first island chain to constantly provoke China's sovereignty in the South China Sea and interfere in Hong Kong and Taiwan affairs.

The United States' superficial recognition of the one-China principle has actually been violated repeatedly. On August 2, 2022, Pelosi visited Taiwan and once again openly trampled on the one-China principle. The Chinese Internet at that time was very shocking. Every social media across the country was filled with calls for war, hoping to liberate Taiwan immediately and break the blockade of the first island chain once and for all. Although the Internet was generally disappointed afterwards, the Russian-Ukrainian conflict and the Palestinian-Israeli conflict that followed that incident made the Chinese people afraid. Because they know that if they start a war recklessly, the battlefield will only be at the doorstep of China. It's a bit far to say, but it can also reflect some of the real situation in China. In the following days, China also made strong resistance to this incident, including trade sanctions, [***diplomatic condemnation***](https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjbxw/202208/t20220809_10738069.html), and military exercises.

---

Although the above two points are not many, I think they are enough to reflect why China has always emphasized that it hopes that China and the United States can have equal dialogue in diplomacy. Double standards and saying one thing but doing another are obviously not equal diplomacy.

PS: How to determine which of the Chinese and English versions of Wikipedia has more content? You can look at the scroll bar on the right. Sentences translated from Chinese into English will become longer. If the scroll bar of the English version is longer than that of the Chinese version (that is, scrolling requires fewer steps to reach the end), it means that the content of the English version is not comprehensive.

Comment: This seems to be a summary of the general sentiment on the Chinese-speaking internet, but what about the Chinese government itself? The question asks "Did **the Chinese government** give any specifics". Can you perhaps find some quotes from official government sources that show that this is also the opinion of the Chinese government and not just of Chinese social media posters?

Comment: If Chinese Wikipedia cites sources the English version doesn't you can always check if those have the information you're talking about and provide a link, quote in Chinese and English translation in your post.

Comment: Can you give an example of a unilateral sanction? And if the US imposes restrictions on China businesses in response to China imposing restrictions on US businesses, how is that not treating China as an equal? "Human rights accusations against Xinjiang, Tibet and other regions without actual evidence." Well, that's just a straight up lie. "provoke China's sovereignty" You aren't using "provoke" correctly. And China's claims of sovereignty in the South China sea are baseless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151336/discussion-between-acccumulation-and-yamakaze).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151377/discussion-between-bharring-and-yamakaze).